# Could not load file or assembly 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll' or one of its dependencies on Click Once Install

Tags: visual-studio, dll, ffmpeg, clickonce, video-processing

My application that has 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll' and supporting DLL's works properly in the development environment. When I publish and try to Click Once install I receive the following message:
Could not load file or assembly 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll'

As suggested in other posts, I copied the following DLL's into my Resources folder in my Visual Studio Project and specified to 'always copy to installation folder'.  I see them in the Install Folder inside the folder  C:\JPGManagerPublish\Application f
Files\JPGManager_3_0_0_179\Resources

avcodec-57.dll
avdevice-57.dll
avfilter-6.dll
avformat-6.dll
avformat-57.dll
avutil-55.dll
postproc-54.dll
swresample-2.dll
swscale-4.dll

These show up in the application install folder as
avcodec.57.dll.deploy, etc.

I install the application with Setup and I when I execute the function that utilizes Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll I get the error message :
'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll'
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to solve it with the following steps:

1. Use the latest package currently available in NuGet.
2. Make sure your application is running in 64-bit mode (check Environment.Is64BitProcess and Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem), if so, download and install Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64 from NuGet only (do not install Accord.Video. FFMPEG).
   [image]
3. If you still face the problem, please check the value of Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() and make sure the dll of FFmpeg is contained in this folder.
4. Try adjusting your PATH variable to include the directory where these .dlls are located (usually in the Bin folder).

   string oldPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path");
   Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", pathToFFmpegDlls + ";" + oldPath);

Comment: In the end I am running a 32 bit environment and this is a Windows App. As the Visual Studio Publish App was putting the required dll's in a \bin directory not in the environment path, it was easier for me to have the application check and move the files to the correct subdirectory (as opposed to changing the environment path).

Awesome help from @wenbingeng-MSFT   THANK YOU !